# Unity Container not registering on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-container

I am a newbie to Windows Phone 8 development but have used Unity before on projects.  I am trying to register some instances and types for use in a WP8 app but it appears the registrations are not being done.  The container is held as a static property of a static class:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static UnityContainer UnityContainer { get; set; }

    public static void InitialiseContainer()
    {
        UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        UnityContainer.RegisterInstance<IActivity>(new FirstActivity());
        UnityContainer.RegisterInstance<IActivity>(new SecondActivity());
        UnityContainer.RegisterType<ActionFactory>(new InjectionConstructor(UnityContainer.ResolveAll<IActivity>().ToList()));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is no registrations are occurring.  Also, if I comment out the `UnityContainer = new UnityContainer()` line, an exception is thrown in the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WindowsPhone.dll` assembly - does Unity behave differently on Windows Phone from Windows desktop?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: The second registration of `IActivity` erases the first. If you do not set `UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();`, then your `UnityContainer` instance is `null`, and an exception is to be expected. Both of these facts are true, as far as I know, on the desktop version of Unity.

Comment: @flq It was a `NullReferenceException` as the Unity Container instance was null.  It was a crude test I used to quickly find out which assembly was being used!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to name your instances:

```
UnityContainer.RegisterInstance<IActivity>("FirstActivity", new FirstActivity());
UnityContainer.RegisterInstance<IActivity>("SecondActivity", new SecondActivity());
```